# UIAlert handling in UIAutomation

Tags: iphone, uialertview, ios-ui-automation

I am trying to test the presence of UIAlertview in app.

From the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/UIAutomationRef/Introduction/Introduction.html) i have added the following handler in the starting of the script.

```
UIATarget.onAlert = function onAlert(alert) {

    var title = alert.name();



    // add a warning to the log for each alert encountered

    UIALogger.logWarning("Alert with title '" + title + "' encountered!");

    UIATarget.localTarget().captureScreenWithName("alert_" + (new Date()).UTC());



    // test if your script should handle the alert, and if so, return true



    // otherwise, return false to use the default handler

    return false;

}
```

But this handler is not being called when the alert pop ups. Can any one help me with this?

Comment: Which Alert is being shown? Is it an alert that you are initiating or is it something like the GPS notification?

Comment: No.Its an alert for failed login...

Answer (score 1):

It might happen if the alert pops up very soon. You can still access its title with

```
UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp().alert().scrollViews()[0].staticTexts()[0].value();
```

Note: leave out `scrollViews()[0]` prior to iOS7.